# MongoDB query also for child elements

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection:

```
[
{
    username : "User1",
    theme : [
        {
            name : "Theme1",
            posts : [
                {
                    text : "test1",
                    postdate : 1,
                    comments : [
                        {username: "User1"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text : "test2",
                    postdate : 2,
                    comments : [
                        {username: "User2"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text : "test3",
                    postdate : 3,
                    comments : [
                        {username: "User3"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
},
```

]

And I want to check if there is a comment by "User1" for the post with the text "test1" . I have tried this so far, but it doesn't work:

```
db.user.find({ "theme.posts.text" : "test1" , "theme.posts.comments.username" : "User1"});
```

EDIT:

The problem is, when I search for "test1" I get a result and when I search for "test2" I also get a result. But I only want a result when the post with the text "test1" has a comment by "User1". So I want to check if a post with text X has a comment by person Y.

What is the right solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell which part is not working ? Is there a expected output you are after ?

Comment: @Veeram Yes! I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that comments is an array. So theme.posts.comments does not have a property called username. Rather theme.posts.comments[0] has a property called username.

One solution would be to get all results with text:"test1" and then use the javascript function indexOf on the array result.comments and see if the object {userName:'User1'} exists in the array.

It would look something like this:

```
db.user.findOne({ "theme.posts.text" : "test1"},function(err,result){
       if(result.comments.indexOf({userName:'user1'}) !==-1){
              console.log("this post has a comment by user1");
}
      else{
         console.log("this post does not have a comment by user1");
}


});
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! And what is the best way to just get the comment[] of the post with "test1"? Because I don't want to look into every array in Java.

Comment: The problem is, When I use findOne I also get the whole document. That means I get all my posts with all the comments. Isn't there a way to just get the comments for this specific post?

Comment: Ah yes, that is because posts: is also an array. You might want to consider restructuring the schema so that you don't have so many nested arrays

Comment: Would be a good idea. I am new to NoSQL/MongoDB so i thought "Let's throw all the stuff in one collection. I did normal tables the last years" :-)